# How to make setting page and other pages beside the main activity content

Tags: android

I am writing simple application that contains setting page and two other pages.
I know how to switch between the pages using Intent (startActivity)

So in using this I can swap between the main activity and the other content pages 
And the setting.

But is there another way? 
What I know till now is that in my case I need to have 4 activities

1. main
2. setting
3. other content page 1
4. other content page 2

I am looking (if there is any of) other way without creating 4 activities.

Comment: You should do a basic android tutorial or read a beginners book to learn this stuff

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is fragments.

for example, you can do a main screen activity with navigation drawer.
by default you can open a mainfragment as the main screen for example, and from the drawer you may access settingsfragment and other screens.
there are several approaches to go by, whatever suits your needs.

you can read about fragments here in the [Android Fragments Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: How can you recommend anything? You know nothing of his app

Comment: @TimCastelijns I appriciate your comment, I really don't know his app or his needs. thanks. edited!